# Action Bar with ActionView for Clickevent doesn't respond

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want a popup dropdown menu with icons opened from a button in the action bar (costumized overflow menu). 
Therefore i give my `MenuItem` an `ActionView` and put a `OnClickListener` on it for opening the popup as dropdown menu under this `View`.

```
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_overflow);
        item.expandActionView();

        final View vs = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getActionView();
        vs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup(MainActivity.this, vs);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

menu_overflow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         />
```

menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
```

the button in the acton bar doesn't respond.

When i declare the action view in the xml, the button responds, but the icon isn't displayed. Like this for example:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having only the ImageButton in menu_overflow.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     />
```

Then inflate the layout into an ImageButton and pass it to the actionview. With the ImageView, add an onclick listener to it.

```
ImageButton iv = (ImageButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_overflow, null);

iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //TODO ADD CODE                    
     }              
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to let your LinearLayout handle clicks by not handling it with the ImageButton (and you can keep the out ViewGroup):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:clickable="false"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    selectedMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
    View actionView=selectedMenuItem.getActionView();

    if(actionView!=null) {
        countTvMenuItem=actionView.findViewById(R.id.count_tv);
        countImageViewMenuItem=actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_ic_image);
    }

    countImageViewMenuItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, CartPage.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });.
```